# XMLInputFactory Error on IPhone App (not on Browser)

Tags: java, confluence, confluence-macros

I have a confusing error on a different behaviour between IPhone Conflunce App Version 1.37.0.1 and Web-Browser.

Technical the macro receives Data (XML) from a Redmine server. The XML is stored in a ByteArray Class.
Storing in a ByteArray allows to cache the Redmine server response for a while.

For parsing it was wrapped by ByteArray Stream:

```
public InputStream httpGetAsInputStream(String url) throws IOException {
   byte[] result = httpGetAsString(url).getBytes(UTF_8);
   return new ByteArrayInputStream(result);
}

private static void parse_xml(InputStream in, TicketState t) throws Exception {
   try {
      // ---> THIS FAILS  on IPhone only
       XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(in);
            ...
    }   ...
}
```

And this is how the methods are invoked:

```
try {
     InputStream strm =  ....httpGetAsInputStream(tmpurl);
     parse_xml(strm, t);
     strm.close();
}
```

The XML Output is parsed and rendered as a HTML-Table.

What is realy confusing to me is that the Webbrowser works like expected, but the IPhone App throws the Exception: *Provider for Class javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory cannot be created*.

[image]

Well that is the server side … there should be no difference between IPhone App and Browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there's an issue with encoding (iphone sending the response using a different encoding to browser).

Why are you reading the HTTP response into a string just to convert it to  a byte array? Why don't you read the response bytes directly into a byte array?